# "No module named... "when running python from terminal

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, python-import, importerror

I've Python 3.6 Installed on my ubuntu. When i try to run my codes via terminal, python doesnt recognize the modules I've installed with pip3. Lets take flask as an example. In the terminal I can do:

```
python3
import flask
```

And I dont get any Import error.But when I've a python file in any location which contains:

```
import flask
```

And i run it via terminal:

```
sudo python file_name.py
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Why python doesnt recognize the modules?

Comment: `python3 file_name.py` ?

Comment: I got the exact same error

Comment: What is your python path?

Comment: /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if flask is installed properly:
try `pip3 freeze` or `pip3 list` from the location where you are trying to run and check if it has flask is in the list.
if it doesn't exists then reinstall and try.

Comment: Can you try running with your python3 version.  ```sudo python3  file.py ``` or if you have 3.6 try ``` sudo python3.6 file.py ```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome . Please consider to click on tick option next to the answer if it helped solving your question.